# How to format table to extract data I want

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want help setting up a data set so I can extract certain data.
I want to be able to extract hours per day.

Basically I am trying to get a utilization for a process on all days used and days not used.
There are days when nothing happens and I want to account for that also.

This is what I want to output in a table visual in Power Bi

| Date | Active (hrs) | Down Time (hrs) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4/1/2022 | 2 | 22 |
| 4/2/2022 | 23.5 | 0.5 |
| 4/3/2022 | 1 | 23 |
| 4/4/2022 | 0.5 | 11.5 |
| 4/5/2022 | 24 | 0 |
| 4/6/2022 | 7.5 | 16.5 |
| 4/7/2022 | 0 | 24 |

This is a sample of my data set. I know I will need to add some columns etc.

| Server | JobName | CreateDate | CreateTime | StartDate | StartTime | EndDate | EndTime | QueueTime | RunTime | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DR-SIM-1 | 0401152430.bat | 4/1/2022 | 3:24:43 PM | 4/1/2022 | 10:11:26 PM | 4/2/2022 | 11:24:48 AM | 406 | 793 | Success |
| DR-SIM-1 | 0401154749.bat | 4/1/2022 | 3:48:03 PM | 4/2/2022 | 11:25:03 AM | 4/3/2022 | 12:49:29 AM | 1177 | 804 | Success |
| DR-SIM-1 | 0404193450.bat | 4/4/2022 | 7:35:22 PM | 4/4/2022 | 7:35:44 PM | 4/6/2022 | 11:55:44 PM | 0 | 3140 | Success |

I am stuck with how to to setup the data table to get this data so I can show on a dashboard.

Comment: you should be able to merge the [StartDate] and [StartTime] together (with a space in between)... and then convert to datetime. then you can just do date math on the two to get a difference.

Comment: You could keep the date and time separate as you have it, this will reduce the size of your data model. Then with DAX in the data set you can calculate the difference with [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datediff-function-dax) with eg: `DATEDIFF([StartDate] + [StartTime], [EndDate] + [EndTime], SECOND)`

Comment: You are more likely to get relevant assistance if you post your data as text which can be easily copy pasted and not as a screenshot.

Comment: I don't understand how output table results from your data set. If active time is the difference between End and Start (or midnight if it overlaps), the numbers you show in your desired visual don't seem to add up.

Comment: The output table is not accurate, it is just an representation of what I desire.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks, I will try to use this. I have not used Power Query before so will see if I can get it to work.
Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate that table in Power Query.

Paste the code below into the Advanced Editor, changing the 2nd line to reflect your actual data source:

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Server", type text}, {"JobName", type text}, 
        {"CreateDate", type date}, {"CreateTime", type time}, 
        {"StartDate", type date}, {"StartTime", type time}, 
        {"EndDate", type date}, {"EndTime", type time}, 
        {"QueueTime", Int64.Type}, {"RunTime", Int64.Type}, 
        {"Status", type text}}),

//Add custom column to create tables which compute the daily use for each row
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Daily Use", (r)=> 
        let 
            Start=r[StartDate] & r[StartTime],
            End = r[EndDate] & r[EndTime],
            Dts = List.Dates(r[StartDate],Duration.Days(r[EndDate]-r[StartDate])+1,#duration(1,0,0,0)),
            #"Daily Use" = 
                List.Accumulate(
                    Dts,
                    {},
                    (s,c)=> s & 
                        {Duration.TotalHours(List.Min({DateTime.From(Date.AddDays(c,1)), End}) - 
                                             List.Max({DateTime.From(c), Start}))})
        in 
            Table.FromColumns(
                {Dts}
                 & {#"Daily Use"},
                 {"Date","Active (hrs)"}
                 ), type table[Date=date, #"Active (hrs)"=number]
            ),

#"Expanded Daily Use" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Daily Use", {"Date", "Active (hrs)", "Down Time (hrs)"}),

//Group by date and Sum the usage for each date
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded Daily Use", {"Date"}, {
        {"Active (hrs)", each List.Sum([#"Active (hrs)"]), type nullable number}, 
        {"Down Time (hrs)", each 24-List.Sum([#"Active (hrs)"]), type nullable number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Your data as supplied:**
[image]

**Results from your data:**
[image]

*Note that if you are doing this in Power BI, you can eliminate the `#"Grouped Rows"` step and create your table visual. In the table visual, you can set it to Sum the values by date, and still have all the other columns available for other visuals*

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work. 
One thing is that each day should not exceed 24 but it does on a number of occasions.
It is common to have multiple jobs per day and for jobs to run over multiple days also.  
Second, how would I show when there was no activity on a given day?

Comment: @Jason.bry There is an error in my posted solution which I will edit to change but is exemplified by `4/2/2022` which is showing 24 hours for both Active and Down times. So far as overlapping times during the day, you did not indicate how you wanted to handle that. So I treated it as total hours worked during the course of a day which could, of course, be more than 24 if multiple tasks are being done at the same time. You will need to develop an algorithm to decide what you want to do, or you could just add code to cap the total at 24.

Comment: @Jason.bry Your data set did not include any days with no activity. What would that look like?